# Event Handler (prop) passed to child component cannot be called react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, event-handling

I am passing an event handler `showSpinner()` from parent component. This method displays the activity Indicator in my app, the method when called from the parent class, works. But when I pass it down to a child component and then call it from the child as `this.props.showSpinner()`, I am getting the error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object
(evaluating 'Object.keys(this.state.data)')
```

I am also not able to `console.log` the method at the child's props
Please note, I have already bound the function at the parent.

Here is a part of my code.
This is the parent component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button, Alert, Image, ScrollView, BackHandler, TouchableOpacity,Text, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import ProductListingItem from '../ProductCategories/ProductListingItemCategories.js';
import PusherColumnCategories from '../ProductCategories/PusherColumnCategories.js';
import NavRightButton from '../NavButton/NavRightButton.js';
import ActivitySpinner from '../ActivitySpinner.js';

const TAG = 'PRODUCTCATEGORIESPAGE';
export default class ProductCategoriesPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    /*this._getResponseFromApi = this._getResponseFromApi.bind(this);*/
    this._onPressGoToCart=this._onPressGoToCart.bind(this);
    if(props){
      /*console.log(TAG,'constructor()','props available');*/
      console.log(TAG,'constructor()','props JSON stringified = '+JSON.stringify(props));
      /*this.setState({dataMain : (props.navigation.state.params.categories)});*/
    }
    this.state = {
      dataMain: props.navigation.state.params.categories,
      showIndicator: false,
    };
    console.log(TAG,'constructor','this.state.dataMain = '+this.state.dataMain );

  }
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return{
      title: 'Categories',
      headerLeft: null,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#EE162C',
      },
      /*headerBackTitleStyle: {
        color: 'white',
      },*/
      headerTintColor: 'white',
      headerRight: <NavRightButton navigation= {navigation}/>,
      gesturesEnabled:false,
    };
  };
  _onPressGoToCart(){
    console.log(TAG,'_onPressGoToCart');
    console.log(TAG,'_onPressGoToCart','navigation props ='+JSON.stringify(this.props));
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('CartPage');
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    console.log(TAG+'componentWillReceiveProps');
    if(newProps){
      console.log(TAG,'componentWillReceiveProps()','props available');
      console.log(TAG,'componentWillReceiveProps()','props = '+newProps.navigation.state.params.categories);
    }
  }
  _OnAlert(title,message){
    console.log(TAG,'_onAlert');
    Alert.alert(
      title,
      message,
      [
        {text:'done',onPress: () => { }}
      ]
    );
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    console.log(TAG,'componentDidMount');
    /*this._getResponseFromApi();*/
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',() => {return true});
  }
  componentWillMount () {
    console.log(TAG,'componentWillMount');
  }
  _showSpinner(){
    console.log(TAG,'_showSpinner');
    this.setState({
      showIndicator:true,
    });
  }
   _hideSpinner(){
   console.log(TAG,'_hideSpinner');
    this.setState({
      showIndicator:false,
    });
  }
  render(){
    console.log(TAG,'render');
    console.log(TAG,'render','dataMain = '+this.state.dataMain[0].id);
    // console.log(TAG,'render','showSpinner = '+JSON.stringify(this.showSpinner()));
    // var tempshowspinner = this.showSpinner.bind(this);
    // console.log(TAG,'render','tempshowspinner = '+JSON.stringify(tempshowspinner));
    return(
      <View
        style={{
          flex:1,
        }}>
        <ScrollView style = {{flex:1,
          backgroundColor:'#F2F2F2',
          }}>
          <View style = {{
            flex:1,
            flexDirection:'column',
          }}>
          <PusherColumnCategories style = {{
            flex:1,
          }}
          data = {this.state.dataMain}
          navigate = {this.props.navigation}
          showSpinner = {this._showSpinner}
          hideSpinner = {this._hideSpinner}/>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <ActivitySpinner showIndicator={this.state.showIndicator}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the corresponding child component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Component, Button} from 'react-native';
import ProductListingItem from './ProductListingItemCategories';
  const TAG = "PUSHERCOLUMNCATEGORIES";
export default class PusherColumnCategories extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    if(props){
      console.log(TAG,'props ='+JSON.stringify(props));
      /*console.log(TAG,'props data length = '+Object.keys(props.dataMain).length);*/
      console.log(TAG,'Props = '+ JSON.stringify(props.data));
      console.log(TAG,'Navigation Props = '+JSON.stringify(props.navigate));
    }

    this.state = {
      data: props.data,
      propsAvailable: false,
      navigate: props.navigation,
    };
  };
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(TAG,'componentDidMount');
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    console.log(TAG,'componentWillReceiveProps',newProps.data);
    this.setState({
      /*data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newProps.data)),*/
      data: (newProps.dataMain),
    }, function() {
      console.log(TAG,'componentWillReceiveProps','this.setState()','data = '+(Object.keys(this.state.data)));
    });
  }
  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log(TAG,'componentDidUpdate');
  }

  render(){
    console.log(TAG,'render()');
    if(this.state.data){
      console.log(TAG,'render()','state not empty');
      console.log(TAG,'render()','data product_code = '+this.state.data[1].product_code);
      return(
        <View style = {{
          flex:1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
        }}>
        <Button
          style = {{
            flex:1,
          }}
          title = 'presshere'
          onClick = {this.props.showSpinner}
          />
        <RenderColumn style = {{
          flex:1,
        }}
         data = {this.state.data}
         navigate = {this.props.navigate}
         showSpinner = {this.props.showSpinner}
         hideSpinner = {this.props.hideSpinner}/>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      console.log(TAG,'render()','state empty');
      return(
        <View style = {{
          flex:1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
        }}/>
      );
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your code so that we can see what you are doing and where you're going wrong? But by the way you're phrasing it, it's probably something to do with function binding and `this`

Comment: Please check the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: I actually found the real problem. The binding stuff is good to know, but it's not the answer to the actual question. The problem is `newProps.dataMain`. `newProps` does not have a `dataMain` key on it, it's actually `data` as you can see below

```
<PusherColumnCategories style = {{
        flex:1,
      }}
      data = {this.state.dataMain} // the key is `data`, not `dataMain`
      navigate = {this.props.navigation}
      showSpinner = {this._showSpinner}
      hideSpinner = {this._hideSpinner}/>
```

So in this piece of code in `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
this.setState({
  /*data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newProps.data)),*/
  data: newProps.data /* not newProps.dataMain */, // newProps.dataMain is not an actual key, so it will set `data` to undefined
}, function() {
  console.log(TAG,'componentWillReceiveProps','this.setState()','data = '+(Object.keys(this.state.data))); // if you call `Object.keys` on undefined, you get the error that you posted
});
```

---

When you do `myFunction.bind(obj)`, you create a new function that wraps your existing function and remembers the object `obj` you pass in, and whenever you call that new function, it calls your original function with `this` set to `obj`.

In your `_showSpinner` an `_hideSpinner` functions, you make use of `this.setState`, so it's important that `this` is set to your parent component so that you update the state of parent component, and you're trying to make sure of that, but you're also binding unnecessarily at a lot of places, like in the constructor of `ProductCategoriesPage`, which is unnecessary. And you also want to remove `bind(this)` from the following

- `tempshowspinner` in the `render` function of `PusherColumnCategories`. `this.props.showSpinner` already updates the parent component since it's bound to it. So it's redundant binding it here again, which gives the wrong impression that you're binding it again to the child component, which is not the case.
- The `bind(this)` in the `Button` component right below. You don't want to bind over here for the same reason

Comment: Hi, most of the binding was done after the initial binding at the constructor did not work. I have updated the code to the current state. Even so, it is not working.

Comment: The bindings in the constructor are redundant because you're binding in the child component's props anyway. And it's not a good practice to reassign class functions, so it's better to do away with the binds in the constructor

Comment: I have done away with the bindings in the constructor. Now the parent method is being called and logs inside the showSpinner() method(which I havent updated in the code here) is being displayed. But still setState is not working, and I am getting the error this.setState is not a function

Comment: Hey @JayakrishnanMenon I found the actual problem in your code. It's `newProps.dataMain` in `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: I didnt get you

Comment: Do you get me now?

Comment: Yes I got you, I removed componentwillupdate from the code. Componentwillreceiveprops was unnecessary, it was garbage code from when I started learning react-native. Now it is working. Apparantly the unnecessary bindings were the problem.

Comment: I am editing your answer and marking it ticked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164614/discussion-between-ambyjkl-and-jayakrishnan-menon).